# Program Freezes while creating new instance of array

Tags: java, arrays

```
    package net.gfx;

public class TileSet {
    public final int TILES = 627;

    class Tiles {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int w = 0, h = 0;
    }

    public Tiles tiles[] = new Tiles[TILES];

    public TileSet() {
        for (int i = 0, y = 0; i < TILES; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 1280; x =+ 25) {
                if (x > 1280) {
                    x = 0;
                    y += 40;
                }

                tiles[i] = new Tiles(); //Program Freezes here
                tiles[i].x = x;
                tiles[i].y = y;
                tiles[i].w = 40;
                tiles[i].h = 40;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is basically create an array of tiles on a screen. I've fixed the original error i was getting here
[Error Setting Object Array Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625967/error-setting-object-array-values) but now it freezes up when i run it. More details in code.

Comment: You don't have a default constructor in the tile class.

Comment: @progenhard Yes he does.

Comment: "Freezes"? You sure it's not throwing an exception, maybe `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: You're setting x equal to positive 25 in the loop. Possibly you meant to increment it.

Comment: @chrylis He will never go out of bounds because he's infinite on the inner loop. He'll be setting the 0th index of the array every time because i never increments.

Comment: Why do you need 2 for loops to initialize a 1-dimensional array? I don't get that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

=+ is not a java operator. You are setting x to the value 25 every time in the x loop.  So you will never get into the case where x > 1280 because every time through the loop (except the first) x will be 25.  You should use the += operator if you wish to increment x by 25 each time through the loop.

Comment: You are amazing for finding this i love you! :D

Comment: You should also know that even with the += operator you will never hit that inner condition in your loop where you are testing for x > 1280.

Answer (score 1):

The last clause of the for is the problem. it is `x =+ 25`. If we wiggle the whitespace a bit we get that it is the same as `x = +25`. Yes, each time, `x` is set to positive 25. You got the `=` and `+` the wrong way around. If you replace it with `x += 25`, your problem should be fixed.